# Asynchronous Function trigger at the the time when new window open over the previous window

Tags: c#, hook, ui-automation

I want to make a such type of asynchronous function which will triggered every time when new window created like we can use mouse hook function so that when user will press particular mouse key then it will be triggered and do some processing or perform any type of functionality.

I have tried that I start a separate thread (windowChangeThread) for window change detection. This thread continuously enumerates windows and checks for changes in the active window title. because this thread is running continously so that we are unable to perform other action.

Comment: like I have a desktop application and it have multiple modules so now we have opened first module so our fuction should be triggered and do processing what we want

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF or something else ?